Why won't my home page redirect to a detail view (Django)
So the context is I'm following a tutorial on codemy.com. Somewhere before Django 5.0 I lost my "magic", the tutorial was written for 3.8 or 4.X maybe. I am showing a function based view although I have tried the class base view as suggested on the codemy youtube. The reason I chose function based view is it was easier for me to debug.
The Home page works fine, however when I try to click on an anchor tag from the home page to redirect to a detail view I get a server 500 Error. I believe the identifier on the homepage that is supposed to locate the document is being passed incorrectly.
views.py
 from django.shortcuts import render
 from django.views.generic import ListView #DetailView
 from django.http import HttpResponse
 from .models import Post


 class Home(ListView):
     model = Post
     template_name = "home.html"


 def articleDetail(request, pk):
     try:
         obj = Post.objects.get(pk=pk)
         return render(request, "article_detail.html", {object, obj})
     except Post.DoesNotExist:
         print("Object number: " + str(pk) + " not found")
         return HttpResponse("Object number: " + str(pk) + " not found")

the model
 from django.db import models
 from django.contrib.auth.models import User


 class Post(models.Model):
     title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
     author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     body = models.TextField()

     def __str__(self):
         return str(self.title) + ' by: ' + str(self.author)

the urls file
 from django.urls import path,include
 from .views import Home, articleDetail

 urlpatterns = [
     path('', Home.as_view(), name="home"),
     path('article/<int:pk>', articleDetail,name="article-detail"),
         ]

the template for home, works fine until redirect
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <title>Landing!!!</title>
     <h1> Home Pageeeeee</h1>
 </head>
 <body>
 <ul>
     <h2>Articles</h2>
     {% for article in object_list  %}
     <li>
         <a href="{$ url 'article-detail' article.pk %}">{{article.title}}</a>
         <br/>
         By: {{article.author}}
         <p>
             {{article.body}}
         </p>
     </li>
     {% endfor %}
 </ul>
 </body>
 </html>

I think my error is either how I'm passing the primary key to look up the object or how I'm asking the URL file to locate the document

You iterate over "object_list", which your function does not send such context: {object, obj}.
If you want to access your articles on homepage, you do not need separate view class or function. Since you use django templating, I assume you do not use JS to load hit the view.
So now you will have articles that you can to loop. You do not need other function (Remove (order_by("-created_at") if you do not have such column, or if you do not want to order articles).
class Home(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = "home.html"
    context_object_name = "articles"

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Post.objects.all().order_by("-created_at")


Thank you so much I've literally been stuck on this for months, when it's an old solution that I had forgotten. I'll try it now and mark as complete when it works

That didn't working changing the Home view just gave me a 500 error on the home page. I think because it's where the page redirects that I get an error. The primary key isn't being passed properly to retrieve the object,
Can I do somethiong like
Post.objects.all.where(primary_key=pk)
Where pk is a parameter I pass to search for the correct object?

Okay I was able to get your code to work without an error 500. I had to either make a migration to have the subfield of post be created by or sort by another option like ID. However my previous comment about the redirect is still applicable. I can't seem to locate the correct document even if I am sorting by the ID's not sure why

Can you more provide information what do you mean redirect? From which page to which page?
Also making migration is not a problem. As I mentioned you can delete this "order_by("-created_at")" part. Since you are dealing with articles, usually one of the columns is "created at" and/or "modified at". Otherwise, you will not have decent ordering to show "Latest articles".

Sorry about that, Just realized I hardly stated what my problem is outside of the title of the problem. I edited the original post to add.
"
The Home page works fine, however when I try to click on an anchor tag from the home page to redirect to a detail view I get a server 500 Error. I believe the identifier on the homepage that is supposed to locate the document is being passed incorrectly."

Marking this as correct, thank you for your assistance.
It took a half of hour of tracing back the debug line. However I was able to read HTTP status codes and see that I was passing parameters between Model View and Template incorrectly, or had a syntactical error.
Thank you for the motivation if nothing else, I have been stuck on this problem for over a year

I am glad that it all worked out. I would highly recommend Youtube channel BugBytes for learning, he has covered such blog/article sites and CRUD operations, especially using HTMX which is so better. Good luck!
